# Fluent NHibernate cascaded save issue with non-unique objects in unique collections

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, save, duplicates

So my data model looks like this:

HEADER -- (has many) --> TASK -- (has zero or one) --> COMPONENT

However even though every TASK may only have one COMPONENT, a COMPONENT may be associated with various TASKs... and when I perform a SaveOrUpdate() I get the following error:

"a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session"

which I validated as true, because more than one TASK does has the same COMPONENT (different object instances, but internally identical). This is initially being read out of the database, which is where my mappings stem from, but apparently I'm missing something in order to save back to the database.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction, as the only way I can think to do this is to save the COMPONENTs separately flushing the session in between each TASK.

Here are my mappings:

HEADER

```
public class Header_ORM: ClassMap<Header> {
  public Header_ORM() {
    Table("HEADER");
    Id(x => x.HeaderID).Length(8);
    .
    . More Mappings
    .
    HasMany<Task>(x => x.Tasks)
      .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
      .KeyColumns.Add("HeaderID")
      .LazyLoad();
}
```

TASK

```
public class Task_ORM : ClassMap<Task> {
  public Task_ORM() {
    Table("TASK");
    CompositeId(x => x.ID)
      .KeyProperty(x => x.HeaderID, x => x.Length(8))
      .KeyProperty(x => x.TaskID, x => x.Length(2));
    Map(x => x.HeaderID).Length(8).ReadOnly();
    Map(x => x.TaskID).Length(2).ReadOnly();
    .
    . More Mappings
    .
    References(x => x.EquipmentComponent)
    .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
    .NotFound.Ignore()
    .LazyLoad()
    .Columns(
      "A",
      "B",
      "C",
      .
      . More Columns
      .
    );
  }
}
```

COMPONENT

```
public class Component_ORM : ClassMap<Component> {
  public Component_ORM() {
    Table("COMPONENT");
    CompositeId(x => x.ID)
      .KeyProperty(x => x.A, x => x.Length(3))
      .KeyProperty(x => x.B, x => x.Length(6))
      .KeyProperty(x => x.C, x => x.Length(6))
      .
      . More Composite Key Columns
      .
    Map(x => x.A).Length(3).ReadOnly();
    Map(x => x.B).Length(6).ReadOnly();
    Map(x => x.C).Length(6).ReadOnly();
    .
    . More Mappings
    .

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I did basically what I said I thought would work (and it did):

```
  using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction()) {
    foreach (WorkOrderTask t in WorkOrder.Tasks) {
      if (t.EquipmentComponent != null) {
        session.SaveOrUpdate(t.EquipmentComponent);
        session.Flush();
        session.Clear();
      }
    }
    session.SaveOrUpdate(WorkOrder);
    transaction.Commit();
  }
```

saving each component first, flushing and clearing the session between saves. This was required due to the fact that I am being given the session, which is stateful. It appears a more proper solution is to use a **stateless session**. I haven't investigated that method further, as I wouldn't be able to use it anyways, but it is worth noting.